# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Wallet with 'id'=hamid)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

am having an issue related to ActiveRecord and am totally stuck in this.
basically am trying to call a controller method from a partial html.erb file. it's passing the username in id when I call it from partial and correct id when I call it from it's original HTML file.

wallets_controller:

```
 before_action :find_wallet, only: %i[update]
  
 def update
   //some code ...
 end
 private

 def find_wallet
    // issue is here...
    @wallet = Wallet.find(params[:id])
 end
```

update.html.erb:

```
    <%= f.fields_for :wallets do |wallet| %>
       <%= render 'wallet_fields', f: wallet %>
       
    <% end %>
```

_wallet_fields.html.erb:

```
 <div class="flex-shrink-1">
 
    <%= link_to update_nfts_wallet_path(wallet: f.object), remote: true, method: :post, class: 'btn btn-icon nfts-refresh-btn' do %>
         <span class="material-icons-outlined">refresh</span>
    <% end %>
 </div>
```

it's throwing this error: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Wallet with 'id'=hamid)
when add my Link_to update_nfts_wallet_path(wallet: f.object) from _wallet_fields.html.erb

and in controller I get actionController like this [image]

and if I add this code in  update.html.erb

```
    <%= f.fields_for :wallets do |wallet| %>
         
        <div class="flex-shrink-1">
 
             <%= link_to update_nfts_wallet_path(wallet), remote: true, method: :post, class: 'btn btn-icon nfts-refresh-btn' do %>
                 <span class="material-icons-outlined">refresh</span>
           <% end %>
      </div>

    <% end %>
```

then in controller, I get ActionController like this:
[image]

I need it the same as this when I call it from partial.
passing the same wallet from partial then why there is different parameters in ActionController. it's not finding the wallet because id have username not an id.

Comment: I got the issue. have to pass the object like this:  update_nfts_wallet_path(id: [f.object])

Answer (score 1):

Change

```rb
update_nfts_wallet_path(wallet: f.object)
```

to

```rb
update_nfts_wallet_path(id: f.id)
```